# What does upstream mean in nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration

```
upstream app_front_static {
    server 192.168.206.105:80;
}
```

Never seen it before, anyone knows, what it means?

Answer (score 266):

It's used for [proxying requests to other servers](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

An example from http://wiki.nginx.org/LoadBalanceExample is:

```
http {
  upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 weight=3;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://myproject;
    }
  }
}
```

This means all requests for / go to the any of the servers listed under upstream XXX, with a preference for port 8000.

Comment: why do you precise **`http {}`**? My conf has not this and it works. Just wondering

Comment: @OlivierPons maybe your config is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` that is included in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, which HAS `http {}`

Answer (score 57):

[`upstream` defines a cluster that you can proxy requests to](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule). It's commonly used for defining either a web server cluster for load balancing, or an app server cluster for routing / load balancing.

Answer (score 29):

If we have a single server we can directly include it in the `proxy_pass` directive. For example:

```
  server {
    ...
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.206.105:80;
      ...
    }
  }
```

But in case if we have many servers we use upstream to maintain the servers. `Nginx` will load-balance based on the incoming traffic, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877989/2135363).

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to `upstream` for one backend server, got too many open file errors etc. This is what I wanted for a test setup proxying towards Mojolicious.