# Setting the backend setting for Apache + Nginx

Tags: nginx, apache2, varnish

```
backend default {
     .host = "localhost";
     .port = "8080";
}
```

At the varnish config, what port should be assigning? I'm using Apache on the backend listening to `1740` and Nginx is listening to `80` with a `proxy_pass` to upstream `127.0.0.1:1740`.

Comment: i think you need more in your question? i don't know, i'm trying to work out nginx myself. have you read this? it was semi - semi - helpful for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877929/what-does-upstream-mean-in-nginx

Comment: forgive me if i'm wrong :P Do you want to know how to configure multiple backends for varnish?

Comment: What do you want out of varnish? A caching layer I hope. But then what is nginx there for? Serving static content? You can do that straight from apache with varnish cache in front. If there is no SSL involved I would just ditch nginx all together.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just nginx + varnish?

nginx and apache are both webserver, of course you can use nginx proxy_pass... but if this is the same server I would ditch apache or nginx... choose one.

In any case "Varnish is a web application accelerator. You install it in front of your web application and it will speed it up significantly." (copy paste form the home page at their site)

So I think first you should decide if you want nginx or apache has you're web server.